# Docker switch back to wsl 2

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have disabled wsl2 option from dcoker desktop.

I did not enabled hyper-v feature of windows.

Now, when I start docker it says

```
Required Windows feature(s) not enabled : Hyper-V.
Docker Desktop will exit.
```

and exists. I cannot start docker.

I do not want to enable hyper-v. Is there any other way, like command or config file, to revert back to wsl2.

Comment: You're probably best off uninstalling docker, deleting your user's AppData/Roaming/Docker directory, and then installing WSL2 from here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel
Then restart and install docker again. But even so, docker still seems to insist on using hyper-V in some capacity even if WSL 2 is set for use. I don't know if it's a bug or not, but it seems like it.

Comment: could always temp install hyper-v just to get it to open so you can switch back, then uninstall hyper-v after - not great i know

Answer (score 0):

- Go to user's AppData/Roaming/Docker
- In settings.json set wslEngineEnabled true

That's worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).